# Setting background to a table with images and text

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a table with text and images with html and css. I want to give a color to the whole table and show image over that back ground color

**HTML**

```
<table>
<tr>
<td class="timg">
<img src="s.jpg" />
</td>
<td>
<p><h3>This is some text </h3> all the bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="timg"><img src="p.jpg" /> </td>
<td> <p> This is some text</p> </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
 .timg{

  height: 100px;
  width: 150px;

  }

.timg img {

  height: 100px;
  width:150px;

  }
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/anbasra/QLNve/1/)

Comment: <table>
<tr>
 <td class="timg">
 <img src="s.jpg" />
 </td>
    <td> <p> <h3>This is some text 
    </h3> all the bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</p> </td>
    
    
</tr>

<tr>
 <td class="timg">
 <img src="p.jpg" />
 </td>
    <td> <p> This is some text</p> </td>
    </tr>
</table>
css file
.timg img { height: 100px; width:150px;}
.timg{height: 100px; width: 150px;}

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/anbasra/QLNve/1/

Comment: You mean like this? http://jsfiddle.net/QLNve/2/

Comment: Actually I need something like this https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8e0BqgjAdM_MjJNV0ZBV21pQjg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Ok like this: http://jsfiddle.net/QLNve/5/ ?

Comment: yes very nearly. How can I put a line under every image to seprayee it from other image

Comment: Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/QLNve/7/